# Cannot import name gpio?

Tags: python

I am getting this error on debian linux. File "app.py" line 2 in 
 from pyA20.gpio import gpio
ImportError: Cannot import name gpio

I can't understand why it isn't working. In the following ling guy says this code works... But mine isn't. What is wrong?
https://diyprojects.io/orange-pi-onelite-tutorial-use-gpio-python-pinouts/#.Wh75RrT1XKJ

Thank you.

```
#import the library / Import des librairies
from pyA20.gpio import gpio
from pyA20.gpio import port
from time import sleep

#initialize the gpio module / initialise le GPIO
gpio.init()

#setup the port (same as raspberry pi's gpio.setup() function)
#Configure la broche PG7 (equivalent au GPIO21 du Raspberry) comme une sortie
gpio.setcfg(port.PG7, gpio.OUTPUT)

#now we do something (light up the LED)
#Maintenant, on allume la LED
gpio.output(port.PG7, gpio.HIGH)

#turn off the LED after 2 seconds
#Et on eteint après 2 secondes
sleep(2)
gpio.output(port.PG7, gpio.LOW)
```

Comment: Your exception shows `py!20` instead of `pyA20` as in your code. Why is that?

Comment: it is typo sorry I will edit. ty.

Comment: Perhaps you need `from pyA20 import gpio` instead?

Comment: I dont know it caused error in the next line says: "File /home/admin/...pyA20/gpio/port/__int__.py", line 5 
import < Something >
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Comment: Is that the *actual* error message, with `__int__` instead of `__init__`, and literally `< Something >` instead of a module name???  We are expecting you to copy & paste error messages, so that we can see *exactly* what is going wrong.

Comment: I am working on embedded system this is why I am writing by hand instead of copy-paste.

Comment: and yes. it is "__init__" which is obvious.